# Error on env.prod, runs on env.dev mode

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

ff I run Webpack with the command

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack. js --env. prod
```

I get the error message below. In --env. dev mode, the command runs through without any problems.

> Can't resolve
>   './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\Users\marco.gall\Source\Solvendi2\Portale-DevMAGA\Portal\ClientApp'
>
> Can't resolve
>   './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\Users\marco.gall\Source\Solvendi2\Portale-DevMAGA\Portal\ClientApp'

There are three files in the storage location, created by template.

- app.module.shared.ts
- app.module.browser.ts
- app.module.server.ts

I'm a little surprised. The problem occurs only in all brunches created by TFS. In the original version, the command works without an error message. The code files are all present.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an **angular** [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8860) that is fixed on master, but is yet to be released: apparently, if you have an unused component, or a component that is used in two modules, and if you compile for ahead-of-time, Angular doesn't relay the proper error message and only gives the generic one like that.

Try rolling back to last stable build you have and figure out what component is included twice (or not at all).

E.g. I've had several **mock** components in a `mock-components.ts`, that were not part of a module. Once I've deleted those (and later, told `tsconfig.app.json` to ignore those), `-prod` build worked properly.

Of course, this was on **ng-cli**, but it's still worth checking out.

Comment: This is only a Copy of another repository. a simple brunch. the original/master works fine. only the bruch have the problem.

Comment: So what is different between the master and your branch?

Comment: I checked every of my code-files. All of them are at the right place. I dont understand this.